# Why is my padding not being removed only from the first child

Tags: css, selection, padding

My first-child of the A:hover tag is removing all the padding instead of only the first child. What is causing this? Thanks guys for any help. Stackoverflow wants more text but I can't say anything more other than I may be having issues with my element selections.

```
     <nav>
            <h2>Navigation</h2>
            <ul>
                    <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Foo</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Roo</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Gamen</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">puta</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
___________________________________________________________________________


    nav li{
        list-style-type:none;
        padding:10px 0px;
        font-size:20px;
        float:left;

    }

    nav h2{
        text-indent: -10000px;
    }
    .Latest_Content{
        clear:both;
    }

    nav a{
        text-decoration:none;
        padding:10px 20px 10px 20px;
        color:#000000;
        font-family:'Droid Sans', sans-serif; 

     }
    nav a:hover{
        color:#ffffff;
        background-color:#42b84f;
        padding:10px 20px 10px 20px;
        -webkit-transition: 0.4s;

    }

    nav a:first-child:hover {
        padding-left:0px;

    }
```

Comment: Did you check if any styles are being applied from other CSS in your project

Comment: @Reddy yes i did i removed it and tried it on jsfiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`a:first-child` will select all first child elements from all lists.

It should be:

```
nav li:first-child a:hover{
  padding-left: 0;
}
```

Now, you are selecting only first list's a tag.

Answer (score 0):

```
    nav a:hover{
        color:#ffffff;
        background-color:#42b84f;
        padding:10px 20px 0px 20px;
        -webkit-transition: 0.4s;

    }

    nav a:first-child:hover {
        padding-left:10px;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution could be:

```
nav li:first-child a{
    padding-left:0px;
}
```

It's because you start list all the `li` and go to the element that want to change.

In your code `nav a:first-child:hover` you try to list the `a` and as you can see on each `li` are just one `a`, that is because all the `a` changes with the `first-child`.